# insert and select data from java with oracle 10g

Tags: java, sql, oracle10g

please how fix this error thanks a lot 
error: package oracle.jdbc.driver does not exist.

tell me how the package install on my PC

for my following code :

```
     import java.sql.*;
     import java.sql.Statement;


    public class ConnectOracle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
        System.out.println("Connecting to the database...");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "system", "123");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("select 'Connected'                                               from dual");
        resultset.next();
        String s = resultset.getString(1);
        System.out.println(s);
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("The exception raised is:" + e);
    }
      }

          }
```

please give me some code to insert and delete (how execute ?!).Thanks .

Comment: please how fix the problem !! oracle.jdbc.driver does not exist.
dose any one help me to fix the errors .??
just the error just

Comment: Include the errors and we can help.  Do you have the Oracle driver library on your class path?

Comment: i deleted answer because im not using textpad so your *.jar is not in classpath, you need to add it to classpath of your project.

Comment: how please ? .what is your editor ? let me downloaded and help me again or re post , please ..

Answer (score 0):

To run a non-query you need to use execute

```
statement.execute("UPDATE ...")
statement.execute("INSERT ...")
statement.execute("DELETE ...")
```

You can see the signtaure of the method here: [java.sql.Statement.execute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

your code is:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
```

Rewrite the above code as below,and it should work

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```